# How to not install trigger more than once with onOpen in google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I don't really understand how to prevent adding the same trigger twice. Except storing data in properties and comparing each time are there any other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get project triggers with [`getProjectTriggers`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getprojecttriggers), then loop them and check for needed one.

For example if you want to check if `onEdit` trigger already set:

```
var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
var editTriggerSet = false;
for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++)
{
  if (allTriggers[i].getEventType() == ScriptApp.EventType.ON_EDIT)
  {
    editTriggerSet = true;
    break;
  }
}

// log the result
Logger.log(editTriggerSet);
```