# Why would forSpreadsheet(ss).onFormSubmit() trigger run too many times (i.e. more than once=7)

Tags: google-apps-script

I am very new to google script (also fairly new to stackoverflow) so excuse any inconvenience.

I modified this guide and ended up with the code at the bottom.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/forms

My ultimate goal is to simply receive some numbers, do calculations on them and return some numbers from different users.

In the code, I use a spreadsheet and create a form, when a response is submitted the code should return an e-mail to the user. Everything works as expected but instead of 1, 7 e-mails are sent.

I simplified the code and it sends the same e-mail each time still does the same (sends 7 emails) with this easier to read version too

Thanks in advance

```
function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name: 'Set up conference', functionName: 'setUpConference_'}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().addMenu('Butten', menu);
}


function setUpConference_() {
  if (ScriptProperties.getProperty('calId')) {
    Browser.msgBox('Your conference is already set up. Look in Google Drive!');
  }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('but');
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  setUpForm_(ss, values);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit').forSpreadsheet(ss).onFormSubmit()
      .create();
  ss.removeMenu('Butten');
}


function setUpForm_(ss, values) {

  var form = FormApp.create('Conference Form');
  var header = form.addSectionHeaderItem().setTitle('Bilgileriniz');
  form.addTextItem().setTitle('Name').setRequired(true);
  form.addTextItem().setTitle('Email').setRequired(true);


  form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());

  var header = form.addSectionHeaderItem().setTitle('Pratik notlariniz');

  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    var session = values[i];
    var ders = session[0].toString();

    var item = form.addTextItem().setTitle(ders);

    var textValidation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
    .setHelpText('0 le 100 arasinda bir sayi olmali')
    .requireNumberBetween(0, 100)
    .build();
    item.setValidation(textValidation);

  }

}


function onFormSubmit(e) {

  MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: 'exp@gmail.com',
  subject: 'exp',
  body: 'exp'});
}
```

Comment: Probably it's because you are not checking how many times 'Set up conference' menu option has been clicked. You can add this check, or just remove `onFormSubmit` triggers before creating new, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/47832134

Comment: Note that the form submit trigger does not specify which form sent the data -only which spreadsheet received it. Thus you only need one on submit trigger (though you may need logic to determine which related method to call to handle a specific form response). Also note that even if your conference call is set up already, you still create a new trigger for it.

Comment: Thank you both, maybe due to my inexpertise, I could only implement the idea @Kos suggested. However, although I added the code in the link just before adding a new trigger the number of triggers is not exactly 1. My first trial sent me 4 emails, then I removed triggers by hand from Edit>All your triggers and now I receive no e-mails. Is there a once and for all way to fix this? I don't actually even need fancy menu option. If this fails I will try to hard-code data into the code and implement it directly on a google form. Instead of getting data from sheets like this here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
function setUpConference_() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var triggerId = ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit")
                           .forSpreadsheet(ss)
                           .onFormSubmit()
                           .create()
                           .getUniqueId();
  Logger.log("New ID: "+triggerId);  

  var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
    if (allTriggers[i].getUniqueId() != triggerId) {
      Logger.log("Delete ID: "+allTriggers[i].getUniqueId()); 
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
    }
  } 

  ss.toast("already done.", "TriggerBuilder"); 
}
```

Comment: Note that `ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers` currently does not retrieve triggers for other users: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36764532 So, your code can still happily create multiple triggers for the same event.